# how to get rows based on Email id with condition where Count is max or latest date

Tags: python, pandas

It is data frame

```
    EmailId City    Count   TrxDate
0   a@gmail.com ben 2   2016-10-07
1   a@gmail.com mum 2   2016-11-29
2   b@gmail.com pune 2  2016-12-10
3   b@gmail.com seh 3   2016-11-10
```

and i want output like where count is max or if count is same then based on latest date

```
    EmailId City    Count   TrxDate
0   a@gmail.com mum 2   2016-11-29
1   b@gmail.com seh 3   2016-11-10
```

Answer (score 2):

sort first then groupby

```
df.sort_values(['Count', 'TrxDate']).groupby('EmailId', as_index=False).last()
```

[image]

Comment: The date should sort in descending, since he requires latest.

Comment: Not entirely sure that's sorted by "latest date"

Comment: @cricket_007 It is greatest `Count` or `TrxDate`.  for the second row, `2016-11-10` is *NOT* the latest date but `3` *IS* the greatest `Count`

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi not if I'm using `last`

Comment: How I understood *if count is same then based on latest date* is that the counts of 2 are all the same, and so the row with the latest date should be selected

Comment: @cricket_007 for `b@gmail.com` `Count` is not the same.  `3 > 2` which I'm sure you know :-) just pointing it out.

Comment: @piRSquared Yes you are right. Missed the email id part :D

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi I've done that far more often than I'd like to admit

Comment: Got it. Question didn't quite clarify that emails were to be grouped by

Comment: @cricket_007 He has mentioned it in title which we missed. In the description he didn't mention properly. piRSquared read the title properly :D

Answer (score 0):

```
df.sort_values(["Count","TrxDate"]).groupby("EmailId").last()
#             City  Count     TrxDate
# EmailId                            
# a@gmail.com  mum      2  2016-11-29
# b@gmail.com  seh      3  2016-11-10
```